# Sympy - output result in derived unit

Tags: sympy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SymPy: How to return an expression in terms of other expression(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038100/sympy-how-to-return-an-expression-in-terms-of-other-expressions)

Consider the following:

```
>>>from sympy.physics.units import *
>>>F=1*N
>>>F
kg*m/s**2
```

How can I force the output to be in the derived unit, N in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SymPy's units only work on base units, so what you want is currently impossible.

There is some work on improving the units system to allow the user to set arbitrary base units.  See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/1389.  It is still development work, so some things might not work with it yet (and it isn't included in the main SymPy development repository yet).